# C# How to connect to different databases based on a flag

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a common function in a C# Webapi project to connect to one of two databases based on the value of an input flag. Each database has the same structure, but different data and each invocation would use the same database throughout.

The rest of my code is database agnostic, so it needs to be able to use a common db object, rather than making the decision every time a call to the database is done.

This is the code I thought would do the trick:

```
public static dynamic GetDb(string scope = "dev") {
    dynamic db;

    if (Globals.db == null) {
        switch (scope.ToLower()) {
        case "tns":
            db = new TnsDb();
            break;

        case "sng":
            db = new SngDb();
            break;

        default:
            db = new TnsDb();
            break;
        }

        Globals.db = db;
    } else {
        db = Globals.db;
    }

    return db;
}
```

I'm using the Entity Framework, which has created an access class for each database I've connected to the project and contains a method for each stored procedure I need to access. What I would like to do is to get this common method to return an object representing the appropriate database class.

The problem I'm having is that the method isn't returning a usable object. I've tried using a return type of dynamic (as above), a plain object and DbContext (the parent class of the Entity Framework db class) and a few other things out of desperation, but each time the calling statement receives back an object that has none of the methods present in the Entity Framework database class.

Any ideas of how to dynamically select and return the appropriate object that does retain all the methods will be gratefully received, as I will be able to save at least some of my hair.

Comment: I'd suggest using a repository pattern, which maps between the db A => web Api domain,  or db B and webApi domain.  you can use AutoMapper to map your domain objects .

Comment: Generics could be useful also

Comment: If the databases are the same, wouldn't the DbContext simply be the same, with just an other connection string? ... well if not: consider a common interface.

Comment: @developer I'm new to C#, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. Can you explain what repository patterns, please? Any code examples would be appreciated too.

Comment: @bradbury9 I'm new to C#, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. Can you explain what generics are, please? Any code examples would be appreciated too.

Comment: @AlphaBeta - your repository maps database entities into your webApi domain model. You say your two DB contexts, will return the same structure of data - so your repositories job is to map this data into the model that your webAPI uses.

Comment: The properties of your db contexts EF models may have same properties, but they are different domains, as will be your web API models.  It's simply a case of making the right call - to the right DB then copying the data returned from your DB domain - to the respective  object in the web api domain.  You can add code to copy each propertie yourself - if there isn't many - or use the NuGet AutoMapper to do this for you.  if you are new to c# I would just write the code to copy the properties between the objects

Answer (score 0):

You mention that each database has the same structure yet your functions uses different db context. You cant use dynamic object in this context using dynamic object.

Since your db has the same structure you could just change the connection string to the db when you initialize the DbContext. If you really want to use separate db contexts then you should use an interfact which your fuctions returns

```
IMyDatabase
{
BbSet<Model1> Model1{get;set;}
BbSet<Model2> Model2{get;set;}
}
TnsDb:IMyDatabase
{
BbSet<Model1> Model1{get;set;}
BbSet<Model2> Model2{get;set;}
}
SngDb:IMyDatabase
{
BbSet<Model1> Model1{get;set;}
BbSet<Model2> Model2{get;set;}
}
```

and both of you context need to implement this then your fuctions could be like this

```
public static IMyDatabase GetDb(string scope = "dev") {
dynamic db;

if (Globals.db == null) {
    switch (scope.ToLower()) {
    case "tns":
        return new TnsDb();

    case "sng":
        return new SngDb();

    default:
        return new TnsDb();
    }
}
```

But you shouldn't be using two separate db context just one would be enough in your case with different connection string

Although using static functions for this purpose not really good, you could some repository pattern using dependency injection

Comment: That might work, but as the context class was auto-generated when I connected the db in Visual Studio, would this interface return all the methods in the auto-generated class or would I have to repeat them all in the interface? I'm new to C#, so I'm not yet familiar with how things work in this language.

Comment: also what is a Bbset? Visual Studio doesn't recognise it?

Comment: Looks like a type, should be `DbSet`

Comment: Thx @bradbury9. That works. I think this might appear to be a silly question, but am I right in thinking that the interface should include every method in the db class or can I get away with just an empty interface?

Comment: All the methods you want to use

Comment: I have this method in the Dbcontext class:
 public virtual ObjectResult<get_Details_Result> get_Details(Nullable<int> id, string username)
and have copied it into the interface as:
 ObjectResult<get_Details_Result> get_Details { get; set; }
but VS keeps saying 'does not implement interface member' and I can't figure out why. I did say I was new to this, didn't I?

Comment: @AlphaBeta: As per your question: `The rest of my code is database agnostic, so it needs to be able to use a common db object`. If you're excluding the possibility of using the existing `DbContext` class in favor of remaining db agnostic, then you're going to have to create your own db agnostic wrapper class (or interface) for it.

Comment: @Flater I tried returning a DBContext from the common method, but kept getting the error that it didn't contain the methods that the db class has. However creating my own interface did work.

Answer (score 0):

Success! I ended up creating an interface that had the same methods as the db class and returned that from the common method.

Here's a snippet from the interface:

```
public interface IDatabase {
    ObjectResult<Method_1_Result> Method_1(Nullable<int> id, string username);
    ObjectResult<Method_2_Result> Method_2(string username, string password);
}
```

and here are the equivalent methods from the db classes:

```
public partial class TnsDb : DbContext, IDatabase {
    public TnsDbDev()
        : base("name=TnsDb")
    {
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Method_1_Result> Method_1(Nullable<int> id, string username)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Method_1_Result>("Method_1", idParameter, usernameParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Method_2_Result> Method_2(string username, string password)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Method_2_Result>("Method_2", usernameParameter, passwordParameter);

    }
}

public partial class SngDb : DbContext, IDatabase {
    public SngDbDev()
        : base("name=SngDb")
    {
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Method_1_Result> Method_1(Nullable<int> id, string username)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Method_1_Result>("Method_1", idParameter, usernameParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Method_2_Result> Method_2(string username, string password)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Method_2_Result>("Method_2", usernameParameter, passwordParameter);

    }
}
```

Note that I had to delete the get and set bodies from the interface method, as they weren't needed and kept generating errors.

I also suspect that this solution is specific to my situation of needing to connect to two databases with exactly the same schema and wouldn't work if the schemas were slightly different, as they couldn't share the same interface.

The technique also requires you to remember to re-add the reference to the interface every time you re-generate the db class (in this case. the TnsDb class) and keep it up to date whenever you change any methods in the db class.

Anyway, I hope that helps anyone with the same problem as I had. Thanks to all that helped me solve this.